# Android::MediaPalyer.seekTo() method not working

Tags: android, media-player, seek

I have a problem with seeking with Android MediaPlayer class. I am playing a local video file, drawing it on a surfaceView. It plays ok, but when I call seekTo(msec) it does not seek. Furhermore, I added a listener (OnSeekComplete) and added callback.

It never gets to the onSeekComplete method. Does anyone know why is that, any  good reason, any good workarond ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems to be a bug in Android platform -- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9135. No reaction on that from Android platform developers though.